# Hyperref: wrong links when listof,bibliography and glossaries in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, glossaries, links

I tried to produce a ToC like this:

```
I    Symbol Glossary
II   Acronyms
1.   Chapter 1
     1.1 Section 1
2.   Chapter 2...
...
III  List of Figures
IV   List of Tables
V    Bibliography
```

So I added the `listof`'s, `glossaries` and `bibliography` to the ToC with success.
But now the ToC links went out of sync. Also the links in the `listof`'s do not match any longer.
Heres a mwe (without bibliography)

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass
[
    pdftex ,
    a4paper ,
    oneside ,
    12pt ,
    halfparskip ,
    headsepline ,
    footsepline ,
    listof=totocnumbered ,
    bibliography=totocnumbered ,
    numbers=noenddot ,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{color}

\usepackage
[
    a4paper ,
    top=3.6cm ,
    bottom=3.6cm ,
    left=3.6cm ,
    right=3.6cm ,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[]{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage
[
    nomain ,
    toc ,
    indexonlyfirst ,
    numberedsection ,
]{glossaries}

\usepackage
[
    block=par ,
    backend=biber ,
    safeinputenc ,
    backref ,
]{biblatex}

\onehalfspacing

\KOMAoptions{draft=on}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{ 0.0 , 0.0 , 1.0 }

\hypersetup
{
    colorlinks          = true ,
    linkcolor           = blue ,
    citecolor           = blue ,
    filecolor           = blue ,
    menucolor           = blue ,
    urlcolor            = blue ,
    bookmarksnumbered   = true ,
}

\newglossary[sym.glg]{sym}{sym.gls}{sym.glo}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\newglossary[acr.glg]{acr}{acr.gls}{acr.glo}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{bla2}
{
    text        = {bla2} ,
    name        = {bla2} ,
    plural      = {bla2} ,
    description = {bla2bla2bla2bla2bla2} ,
    type        = {acr} ,
    sort        = {bla2} ,
}

\newglossaryentry{bla1}
{
    text        = {bla1} ,
    name        = {bla1} ,
    plural      = {bla1} ,
    description = {bla1bla1bla1bla1bla1} ,
    type        = {sym} ,
    sort        = {bla1} ,
}

% \addbibresource{eli_bib.bib}

\title{\textbf{Title}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\printglossary[type=acr,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\printglossary[type=sym,title=Symbolverzeichnis]

\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}


\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}

\gls{bla1} blablabla \gls{bla2}

\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}
\chapter{test}\section{test}


\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]

\end{document}
```

I compile the PDF this way:

```
pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -draftmode %doc%.tex
makeindex -s %doc%.ist -t %doc%.sym.glg -o %doc%.sym.gls %doc%.sym.glo
makeindex -s %doc%.ist -t %doc%.acr.glg -o %doc%.acr.gls %doc%.acr.glo
biber %doc%
pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -draftmode %doc%.tex
pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -synctex=1 %doc%.tex
```

What went wrong here? (I tried even to put `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection` almost everywhere in different positions so far)

---

### EDIT #1:

I stripped the guts out to a minimal mwe, where the back links in the glossaries are still wrong:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}

\newglossary[sym.glg]{sym}{sym.gls}{sym.glo}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\newglossary[acr.glg]{acr}{acr.gls}{acr.glo}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{bla2}{name={bla2},description={bla2bla2bla2bla2bla2},type={acr}}
\newglossaryentry{bla1}{name={bla1},description={bla1bla1bla1bla1bla1},type={sym}}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=acr]\printglossary[type=sym]

\chapter{test}\section{test}\chapter{test}\section{test}
\gls{bla1} blablabla \gls{bla2}
\chapter{test}\section{test}\chapter{test}\section{test}

\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT #2:

I'd like to share my compilation-batch file (I couldn't find a good one in the www):

[GitHub- Gist](https://gist.github.com/serthy/cfd3a53e21668aa18897)

```
:: sumatrapdf.exe is in miktex/miktex/bin
:: biber.exe in miktex/miktex/bin
:: sumatrapdf: einstellungen > optionen : 'pfad/zu/sublime_text.exe %f:%l:100000' eintragen
:: call this batch file like: 'tex.bat myTexFile' (myTexFile without any extension)

@echo off

setlocal

set document=%~n1
set miktexpath=C:/bin/programme/miktex/miktex/bin

set path=%path%;%miktexpath%;

call :deletetemporaries
call :compile

goto final

:compile
    echo ! Begin Compilation
    call :buildtex

    if errorlevel 1 (
        call :syntaxerror
    ) else (
        call :buildglossaries
        call :buildbib
        call :buildtex
        call :buildglossaries
        call :buildpdf
        call :showpdf
        call :deletetemporaries
    )

:deletetemporaries
    echo ! Delete temporaries
    del /s *glg >nul 2>&1
    del /s *gls >nul 2>&1
    del /s *glo >nul 2>&1
    del /s *blg >nul 2>&1
    del /s *bbl >nul 2>&1
    del /s *toc >nul 2>&1
    del /s *out >nul 2>&1
    del /s *log >nul 2>&1
    del /s *lot >nul 2>&1
    del /s *lof >nul 2>&1
    del /s *ist >nul 2>&1
    del /s *bcf >nul 2>&1
    del /s *aux >nul 2>&1
    del /s *run.xml >nul 2>&1
goto end


:buildglossaries
    makeindex -s %document%.ist -t %document%.sym.glg -o %document%.sym.gls %document%.sym.glo 2>nul
    makeindex -s %document%.ist -t %document%.acr.glg -o %document%.acr.gls %document%.acr.glo 2>nul
    makeindex -s %document%.ist -t %document%.idx.glg -o %document%.idx.gls %document%.idx.glo 2>nul
goto end

:buildpdf
    pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -synctex=1 %document%.tex 1>nul
    echo.
goto end

:buildtex
    pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -draftmode %document%.tex 1>nul
goto end

:buildbib
    biber %document% 2>nul
goto end

:syntaxerror
    pdflatex -draftmode %document%.tex
    echo ! Compilation failed
goto end

:showpdf
    SumatraPDF -reuse-instance %document%.pdf 1>nul
goto end

:final
    echo ! Compile done
    echo.
    exit

:end
    goto:eof
```

Comment: Why do you have `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection` before `\printglossary`? The `toc` package option does `\phantomsection` automatically at the start of each glossary (and `\cleardoublepage` is automatically inserted regardless of the `toc` option for book-like classes).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that, I removed it from this example, but still, the back-link in the glossaries refer to the wrong pages

Comment: I could not decide which answer to choose as *the* answer, both of them solved my problem in combination. Thanks to you two!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The insertion of the glossaries and other lists cause the page numbers to change so you need to do:

```
pdflatex
makeglossaries
pdflatex
makeglossaries
pdflatex
```

to get them up-to-date.

The first `makeglossaries` generates the glossaries but uses the page numbers from the first LaTeX run, so you need another LaTeX run to update the page numbers, then rerun `makeglossaries` to update the back-references and rerun LaTeX to update the document.

Answer (score 5):

You get messages saying something like

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{chapter.4
}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

which shouldn't be ignored. They are caused by having chapters with the same number.

You can solve it by adding

```
\renewcommand\theHchapter{\thechapter}
```

after doing `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}`. In this way `hyperref` will use a unique internal identifier for chapters and return in sync.

Comment: Thank you! The links in the ToC are now working! However the backlinks from the glossaries to its first use are still out of sync

Comment: There's no `\gls` in your sample. If I add `\gls{bla2}`, then the link in the glossary points to it.

Comment: Huh? Isn't there a `\gls{bla1} blablabla \gls{bla2}` right in the middle?

Comment: Do I have to add the `\renewcommand\theHchapter{\thechapter}` after every `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{...}` entry? Or only after this specific one with Roman?

Comment: Oh it should mean `renewcommand` instead of `renewcomand` (one *m* is missing)

Comment: @Serthy Sorry for the typo.